# warning# Git command failed with status: exit code: 128

Tags: substrate

I am following the tutorial [importing contracts pallet], and [cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 build] - load successfully, although there are 2 warnings: Git command failed with status: exit code: 128 &  Could not find `.git/HEAD`.
Is this a bug or is there code to remove warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks bkchr for your comment! [This warnings comes when you don't execute the compilation in a git repo. However it is fine to ignore and nothing bad happens ;)]